# AJAX/JS form prevents cookie from being set

Tags: php, ajax, cookies

### SOLVED:

Add `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` to .htaccess file and then amend the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the domain where the AJAX call is being sent from. The AJAX call must include:

```
xhrFields: {
   withCredentials: true
},
```

--

Ihave an API call at my backend which sets a cookie in the browser and is working fine if I submit the user login details through a normal HTML form. However if to the form I then add AJAX to prevent event defaults and get the reply back from the server, the cookie is not being set...

```
{{-- Log In Form Script --}}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function() {
            $('#login-form').submit(function(event) {
                // event.preventDefault();

                var formEl = $(this);
                var submitButton = $('input[type=submit]', formEl);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: formEl.prop('action'),
                    accept: {
                        javascript: 'application/javascript'
                    },
                    data: formEl.serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        submitButton.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                    },
                    statusCode: {
                        401: function() {
                            $("#login-button").css('background-color','red');
                            $('#login-submit-label').text('Incorrect Email or Password!');
                            //replace with data.message
                            $("#login-submit-label").show();
                        },
                        403: function() {            
                            $("#login-button").css('background-color','#ffbf00');
                            $('#login-submit-label').text('Account not activated. Check your inbox!'); 
                            //replace with data.message
                            $("#login-submit-label").show();
                        }           
                    }
                }).done(function(data) {    
                    if((data.status == "ACCESS") || (data.status == "COOKIE")){
                        $("#login-button").css('background-color','#1e3296');
                        // var button = document.getElementById("login-button");
                        // button.classList.toggle("btn-custom");
                        $("#log-in-spinwheel").show();
                    }else{
                        //
                    }
                    console.log(data);  
                    submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Cookie being set as follows:

```
setcookie('auth_token', $randomtoken, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
```

.htaccess file already has the following lines of code for CORS error:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Comment: What is the form action pointing to, is this a cross-origin request by any chance?

Comment: The form from my frontend is pointing to my backend(different subdomain than frontend). What do you mean by cross-origin please?

Comment: As regards CORS, I had already added the following lines of code in my .htaccess file since all AJAX calls were being blocked (see edited post)

Comment: That is not enough, you need to specifically allow cookies. `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` on the server side, and `withCredentials` set to true for the AJAX request.

Comment: I added those lines of code, however I am now getting the following error:
...has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: Yes, you need to respond with the specific origin in this case.

Comment: @misorude, ok managed! added the domain of my frontend in the Allow-Origin, thank you! :)